# Массивы строк и их индексы

Tags: c++

Почему не работает этот код? А если точнее, именно действие `text[t] = "Sometext"`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, i;
    char text[100][80];

    for (t = 0; t < 100; t++)
    {
        cout << t << ": ";
        text[t] = "Sometext";
        if (!text[t][0]) break;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < t; i++) cout << text[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

В то время как `gets(text[t]);` работает.

Компилятор Visual Studio 2013
Ошибки:

```
Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [3]' to 'char [80]'  c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\practice\practice8\myprog.cpp   13  1   practice8
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C и в C++ массивы не имеют операторов присваивания. Например, если у вас имеется два массива

```
int a[2] = { 1, 2 };
int b[3]; // или дааже int b[2];
```

то вы не можете написать

```
b = a;
```

Вы можете только копировать отдельные или все элементы из одного массива в другой. Например

```
size_t i = 0;
for ( ; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); i++ )
{
    b[i] = a[i];
}

b[i] = 3;
```

конечно вместо использования цикла вы могли бы использовать стандартный алгоритм `std::copy`, объявленный в заголовке `<algorithm>`, чтобы выполнить ту же самую операцию. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int a[2] = { 1, 2 };
    int b[3];

    *std::copy( a, a + sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ), b ) = 3;

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int x : b ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Результатом работы программы будет вывод на консоль

```
1 2 
1 2 3
```

Символьные массивы в C и в C++ могут хранить строки, то есть последовательность символов, завершаемую нулем `'\0'`.

Так, например, строковый литерал `"Sometext"` имеет в C++ тип символьного масива `const char[9]`, и может быть представлен как

```
{ 'S', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'e', 'x', 't', '\0' }
```

Вы также для копирования символьных массивов, которые содержат строки можете использовать циклы и стандартный алгоритм `std::copy`. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char text[100][80];
    char s[] = "Sometext";

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t n = std::strlen( s );

    for ( ; i < n; i++ )
    {
        text[0][i] = s[i];
    }

    text[0][i] = '\0';

    *std::copy( s, s + std::strlen( s ),text[1] ) = '\0';

    std::cout << text[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << text[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Результатом работы этой программы будет вывод на консоль

```
Sometext
Sometext
```

Для копирования символьных строк в стандарте языка C определены дополнительные функции такие, как `strcpy`, `strncpy`, `strcat` и другие, которые объявлены в заголовке языка C `<string.h>`, который в программах, написанных на C++, следует записывать как `<cstring>`

Например, с использованием функции `strcpy` программа, показанная выше могла бы выглядеть как

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char text[100][80];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
        std::strcpy( text[i], "Sometext" );
    }

    std::cout << text[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << text[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Ее конечный результат был бы идентичен результату предыдущей программы.

Что касается данного предложения из вашей программы

```
text[t] = `"Sometext"`;
```

то строковый литерал `"Sometext"`, который в C++ имеет тип массива `const char[9]`, как было указано выше, в этом выражении с оператором присваивания преобразуется в указатель `const char *`, который указывает на первый символ строкового литерала. И этот указатель вы пытаетесь присвоить массиву. Компилятор выдает сообщение об ошибке, потому что этого делать нельзя.

Вы могли бы этот указатель присвоить другому указателю, если, например, ваш массив был объявлен как

```
const char * text[100];
```

В этом случае предложение

```
text[t] = `"Sometext"`;
```

было бы корректным, так как тип выражения `text[t]` и тип выражения `"Sometext"` оба имеют в данном предложении тип `const char *`.

Answer (score 5):

В С++ строки - это массивы, например "123" это массив `const char[4]`.

В С++ нет встроенной операции присваивания для массивов, только инициализация.

По этому Вам надо использовать `strcpy` или другую функцию копирующую строку или массив.